# Error in escalc 'Supplied data vectors are not all of the same length.'

Tags: r, metafor, meta-analysis

When running the escalc(measure="SMD" a persistent error message is returned - Error in escalc... Supplied data vectors are not all of the same length.

```
  tc_effect <- escalc(measure="SMD",
  m1i=treat_control$TreatMeanChange, 
  sd1i=treatment_sd, 
  n1i=treat_control$treatment_n, 
  m2i=treat_control$ControlMeanChange, 
  sd2i=control_sd, 
  n2i=treat_control$control_n, 
  data=treat_control) 

##Check for NA values in critical vectors**

   <pre> <code> sum(is.na()

# [1] 0 for all<br/>

# Verify the lengths of vectors****

      length()

#[ 1] 25 for all<br/>

# Verified structure

      str()

# num [1:25] for all<br/>
```

Comment: Please define an example of input data with dput to create a minimial reproducible example.